# How do I invoke a JS object (such as datepicker) method using the HTML id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the following code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {$( '.dateTxt' ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dates) { alert('The chosen date(s): ' + dates); },
                });
$( ".dateTxt" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <p>Date 1: <input id="one" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></p>
        <p>Date 2: <input id="two" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></p>
        <p>Date 3: <input id="three" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to pass different dates to the constructor and unique vectors.  How do I do that?

In the example, I'd like to initialize each field with a unique date -- and unique HTML vector when a new date has been chosen.  Of course, I'd like to do it with one class, as shown in the example.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id selector `#id` as follows:

```
$( '#one' ).datepicker( ....  );

$( '#two' ).datepicker( ....  );

$( '#three' ).datepicker( ....  );
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I pass dates to the constructor during instantiation?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  defaultDate works in the constructor, I need 3 different dates passed to the constructor when I initialize the HTML element.